# Transfer coordinates from one triangle to another triangle

Tags: geometry, coordinate

I have two triangles , which can be in any sizes. The problem is that, how I can transfer coordinates from one triangle to another? I know both of triangle position in coordinate system and yes, they both are in one system.

Basically, i have point in triangle1 and I need to transfer it in triangle2.

Reading some posts, I found out that I could be calculated using **affine transformation matrix**, but I didn't undestand how to solve this with affine transformation matrix.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let you have unknown affine transformation matrix

```
   | a c e |
M =| b d f |
   | 0 0 1 |
```

The first triangle vertices are `(xa1, ya1), (xa2, ya2), (xa3, ya3)`, and the second triangle vertices have coordinates `(xb1, yb1), (xb2, yb2), (xb3, yb3)`.

Then affine transformation **M** that transforms the first triangle vertices to the second one vertices is:

```
M * A = B
```

where

```
   | xa1 xa2 xa3 |
A =| ya1 ya2 ya3 |
   |  1   1   1  |

   | xb1 xb2 xb3 |
B =| yb1 yb2 yb3 |
   |  1   1   1  |
```

To find unknown **M**, we can multiply both sides of the expression by inverse of **A** matrix

```
M * A * Inv(A) = B * Inv(A)
M = B * Inv(A)
```

Inversion of **A** is rather simple (calculated by Maple, may contain errors due to my typos):

```
| (ya2-ya3)    -(xa2-xa3)    (xa2*ya3-xa3*ya2)  |
| -(-ya3+ya1)  (-xa3+xa1)    -(xa1*ya3-ya1*xa3) | * 1/Det
| (-ya2+ya1)   -(-xa2+xa1)   (xa1*ya2-ya1*xa2)  |
```

where determinant value is

```
Det = xa2*ya3-xa3*ya2-ya1*xa2+ya1*xa3+xa1*ya2-xa1*ya3
```

So you can find affine matrix for needed transformation and apply it to coordinates (multiply **M** and `(x,y,1)` column matrix)

Comment: Once you have M, how would you apply it to coordinates ?

Comment: Oh, I know, just prettend you have a `x,y,1` matrix !

Comment: good answer, even good enough to copy and paste into my code... The texture mapping works.