# Calculating the angles of the rotation giving the vertices

Tags: rotation, geometry, augmented-reality

I have 4 points (black A, black B, black C and black D) which are the vertices of the rotated red square.
Is it possible to determine what were the three angles (x angle, y angle and z angle) used to rotate the red square into the black square?
In this case, the angles were:
`X = 1rad
Y = 0.2rad
Z = 0.3rad`
[image]

EDIT: I just have the four black points, not the red ones.
The only thing I know about the red square is that it is a square

Comment: What do you know about the red square? Do you know its orientation?

Comment: Just that it is a square

Comment: What about the orientation? How do you know that it is not already in the same orientation as the black one?

Comment: That's what I'd like to find. If every angle is equals to zero, then it is the same square

Comment: Then this solution is as likely as any other. Since you don't know anything about the red square, it could just be equal to the black one already.

Answer (score 0):

There is method to find affine matrix needed to transform point set into another one.
Having natrix, you can find angles.

Description for 2D case [is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844000/transfer-coordinates-from-one-triangle-to-another-triangle/18848074#18848074), 3D case is similar.

```
 M * A = B
```

where

```
    | xa xb xc xd|
 A =| ya yb yc yd|
    | za zb zc zd|
    | 1  1  1  1 |

    | xa' xb' xc' xd'|
 B =| ya' yb' yc' yd'|
    | za' zb' zc' zd'|
    |  1   1   1   1 |
```

To find unknown M, we can multiply both sides of the expression by inverse of A matrix

```
 M * A * Inv(A) = B * Inv(A)
 M = B * Inv(A)
```

But solution is unique for non-complanar point quadruplet - in your case points lie in the same plane, so if solution exists, it is really a family of solutions and you have to choose arbitrary one. (Perhaps angles will be defined unambiguously)

Comment: I don't know the coordinates of the red square's vertices