# Closed form solution for affine transformation matrix between 2 set of 2D points

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra, sympy, maple, affinetransform

Given affine transform equation with 6 unknown variables `a_11, a_12, a_21, a_22, b_1, b_2` and corresponding 3 pairs of points `x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3`:

```
u = a_11 * x + a_12 * y + b_1
v = a_21 * x + a_22 * y + b_2
```

Is it possible to get solution for `a_11, a_12, a_21, a_22, b_1, b_2` in the this form?

```
a_11 = f1(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3)
a_12 = f2(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3)
a_21 = f3(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3)
a_22 = f4(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3)
b_1 = f5(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3)
b_2 = f6(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3)
```

I know that this system can be solved via linear system solver like [numpy.linalg.solve](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html#:%7E:text=solve,-numpy.linalg.&text=Solve%20a%20linear%20matrix%20equation,linear%20matrix%20equation%20ax%20%3D%20b.), but I can't use it and I need `f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6` to contain common math operations.

Is it possible in general? Which tools can be used to solve such system of equations? Seems [maple](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=solve#examples) and [mathematica](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) have equation solver, is it suitable for this task? is there any alternatives?

Comment: If you write all 6 equations, isn't this just linear algebra. Like row reduce with unknowns to get your answer. I'll take a stab at it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844000/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I used `sympy` to solve this system of equations:

```
from sympy.solvers.solveset import linsolve
from sympy import *

    #u1 = a_11 * x1 + a_12 * y1 + b_1
    #v1 = a_21 * x1 + a_22 * y1 + b_2
    #u2 = a_11 * x2 + a_12 * y2 + b_1
    #v2 = a_21 * x2 + a_22 * y2 + b_2
    #u3 = a_11 * x3 + a_12 * y3 + b_1
    #v3 = a_21 * x3 + a_22 * y3 + b_2

    a_11, a_12, a_21, a_22, b_1, b_2, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3 = \
        symbols('a_11, a_12, a_21, a_22, b_1, b_2, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, u1, v1, u2, v2, u3, v3')

    s = linsolve([a_11 * x1 + a_12 * y1 + b_1-u1,
                  a_21 * x1 + a_22 * y1 + b_2-v1,
                  a_11 * x2 + a_12 * y2 + b_1-u2,
                  a_21 * x2 + a_22 * y2 + b_2-v2,
                  a_11 * x3 + a_12 * y3 + b_1-u3,
                  a_21 * x3 + a_22 * y3 + b_2-v3], (a_11, a_12, a_21, a_22, b_1, b_2))

    print(s)
```

The answer is:

```
a_11 = (u1 * y2 - u1 * y3 - u2 * y1 + u2 * y3 + u3 * y1 - u3 * y2) / (
             x1 * y2 - x1 * y3 - x2 * y1 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y1 - x3 * y2)

a_12 = (-u1 * x2 + u1 * x3 + u2 * x1 - u2 * x3 - u3 * x1 + u3 * x2) / (
            x1 * y2 - x1 * y3 - x2 * y1 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y1 - x3 * y2)

a_21 = (v1 * y2 - v1 * y3 - v2 * y1 + v2 * y3 + v3 * y1 - v3 * y2) / (
            x1 * y2 - x1 * y3 - x2 * y1 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y1 - x3 * y2)

a_22 = (-v1 * x2 + v1 * x3 + v2 * x1 - v2 * x3 - v3 * x1 + v3 * x2) / (
            x1 * y2 - x1 * y3 - x2 * y1 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y1 - x3 * y2)

b_1 = (u1 * x2 * y3 - u1 * x3 * y2 - u2 * x1 * y3 + u2 * x3 * y1 + u3 * x1 * y2 - u3 * x2 * y1) / (
            x1 * y2 - x1 * y3 - x2 * y1 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y1 - x3 * y2)

b_2 = (v1 * x2 * y3 - v1 * x3 * y2 - v2 * x1 * y3 + v2 * x3 * y1 + v3 * x1 * y2 - v3 * x2 * y1) / (
            x1 * y2 - x1 * y3 - x2 * y1 + x2 * y3 + x3 * y1 - x3 * y2)
```

But it looks like it can be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the points (x1,y1,u1,v1), (x2,y2,u2,v2), and (x3,y3,u3,v3) satisfy the equations. In such case, substituting those in, yields six equations with six unknowns. Many of the coefficients are zero or one. Hence with a bit of canceling we get your requested solutions.

Your solutions (assuming you have linear independence) are:

```
a11 = ((u1-u2)(y2-y3)-(u2-u3)(y1-y2))/((x1-x2)(y2-y3)-((x2-x3)(y1-y2))
a12 = ((u1-u2)(x2-x3)-(u2-u3)(x1-x2))/((y1-y2)(x2-x3)-((y2-y3)(x1-x2))
a21 = ((v1-v2)(y2-y3)-(v2-v3)(y1-y2))/((x1-x2)(y2-y3)-((x2-x3)(y1-y2))
a22 = ((v1-v2)(x2-x3)-(v2-v3)(x1-x2))/((y1-y2)(x2-x3)-((y2-y3)(x1-x2))
b1 = u1-a11×x1-a12×y2
b2 = v1-a21×x1-a22×y2
```

I should point out. This question is more for mathoverflow. Really has nothing to do with programming.