# How to solve overdetermined linear system X * A = B?

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra, affinetransform

How to solve overdetermined linear system `X * A = B`, `A, B` is given and I need to find `X`?

It seems solution is straightforward for square matrices(https://stackoverflow.com/a/18848074/1179925):

```
X * A = B
M * A * Inv(A) = B * Inv(A)
M = B * Inv(A)
```

But how to deal with non square matrices?

Example code:

```
def to_homogeneous(_pts):
    n = _pts.shape[0]
    _pts = _pts.transpose()
    pts = np.ones((3,n), np.float32)
    pts[:2,:] = _pts
    return pts

def get_random_affine_matrix():
    src_tri = np.random.rand(3,2) * np.random.randint(1,10)
    src_tri = src_tri.astype(np.float32)
    src_tri = to_homogeneous(src_tri)
    
    dst_tri = np.random.rand(3,2) * np.random.randint(1,10)
    dst_tri = dst_tri.astype(np.float32)
    dst_tri = to_homogeneous(dst_tri)
    
    m = dst_tri @ np.linalg.inv(src_tri)
    
    print('-'*60)
    print('src_tri.shape', src_tri.shape)
    print('src_tri:')
    print(src_tri)

    print('-'*60)
    print('dst_tri.shape', dst_tri.shape)
    print('dst_tri:')
    print(dst_tri)

    print('-'*60)
    print('m.shape', m.shape)
    print('m:')
    print(np.round(m, 5))

    return m

m = get_random_affine_matrix()

src_pts = np.random.rand(4,2) * np.random.randint(1,10)
src_pts = src_pts.astype(np.float32)
src_pts = to_homogeneous(src_pts)

dst_pts = m @ src_pts

print('-'*60)
print('src_pts.shape', src_pts.shape)
print('src_pts:')
print(src_pts)

print('-'*60)
print('dst_pts.shape', dst_pts.shape)
print('dst_pts:')
print(dst_pts)

m = dst_pts @ np.linalg.inv(src_pts) # Gives LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

Output:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
src_tri.shape (3, 3)
src_tri:
[[2.7440674 3.0138168 2.118274 ]
 [3.5759468 2.724416  3.2294705]
 [1.        1.        1.       ]]
------------------------------------------------------------
dst_tri.shape (3, 3)
dst_tri:
[[0.5950692  0.5453126  1.6243374 ]
 [0.11342596 0.95533025 0.9599543 ]
 [1.         1.         1.        ]]
------------------------------------------------------------
m.shape (3, 3)
m:
[[-1.42684 -0.39356  5.91778]
 [-0.68516 -1.20574  6.30521]
 [ 0.       0.       1.     ]]
------------------------------------------------------------
src_pts.shape (3, 4)
src_pts:
[[8.33037    0.7841637  7.4935784  7.830109  ]
 [0.63932455 0.18196557 7.003411   8.807565  ]
 [1.         1.         1.         1.        ]]
------------------------------------------------------------
dst_pts.shape (3, 4)
dst_pts:
[[-6.2199397   4.7272906  -7.5306525  -8.7208805 ]
 [-0.17327118  5.5485325  -7.2733746  -9.679293  ]
 [ 1.0000011   1.0000001   1.0000015   1.0000017 ]]

LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square
```

Comment: You use the pseudo-inverse for non-square matrices: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse with `np.linalg.pinv`: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html

Comment: Also for what it's worth you can use OpenCV to apply, invert, etc typical transformations. For e.g., see `cv2.invertAffineTransform`: https://docs.opencv.org/master/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga57d3505a878a7e1a636645727ca08f51

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the best solution would be using numpy's `lstsq` function:

rewriting your system like this

```
#X*A = B <=> A.T*X.T = B.T
```

lets us use

```
Xt = np.linalg.lstsq(A.T, B.T)
X = Xt.T
```

This is a better solution both in terms of speed and accuracy to using inverses and pseudo-inverses, and unless you explicitly need these I would strongly recommend that you don't use them

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve it using pseudoinverse:

```
# X * A = B
# X * A * A.tr() = B * A.tr()
# X = B * A.tr() * Inv(A * A.tr())

m2 = dst_pts @ src_pts.transpose() @ np.linalg.inv(src_pts @ src_pts.transpose())
```