# Map corresponding points between Delaunay triangles

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-image, affinetransform, delaunay

I'm trying to morph two images of faces using an inverse warp. I have the Delaunay triangles for both images as well as all transformation matrices for all pairs of corresponding triangles.
[image]

I have applied the matrix to every pixel inside the triangles, but the image I am getting is all messed up and some pixels aren't being filled in as well.

[image]

I suspect the vertices lists are not in order which means the triangles are not corresponding. Or it could just be me messing up the row, cols order.

Here's my code:

```py
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from skimage.draw import polygon
import numpy as np

def drawDelaunay(img, landmarks, color):
    tri = Delaunay(landmarks)
    vertices = []

    for t in landmarks[tri.simplices]:
        # t = [int(i) for i in t]
        pt1 = [t[0][0], t[0][1]]
        pt2 = [t[1][0], t[1][1]]
        pt3 = [t[2][0], t[2][1]]

        cv2.line(img, pt1, pt2, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA, 0)
        cv2.line(img, pt2, pt3, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA, 0)
        cv2.line(img, pt3, pt1, color, 1, cv2.LINE_AA, 0)    

        vertices.append([pt1, pt2, pt3])
    return img, vertices


def getAffineMat(triangle1, triangle2):
    x = np.transpose(np.matrix([*triangle1]))
    y = np.transpose(np.matrix([*triangle2]))

    # Add ones to bottom of x and y
    x = np.vstack((x, [1,1,1]))
    y = np.vstack((y, [1,1,1]))

    xInv = np.linalg.pinv(x)
    return np.dot(y, xInv)


srcImg = face2
srcRows, srcCols, srcDepth = face2.shape
destImg = np.zeros(face1.shape, dtype=np.uint8)

for triangle1, triangle2 in zip(vertices1, vertices2):
    transMat = getAffineMat(triangle1, triangle2)
    r, c = list(map(list, zip(*triangle2)))
    rr, cc = polygon(r, c)

    for row, col in zip(rr, cc):
        transformed = np.dot(transMat, [col, row, 1])
        srcX, srcY, *_ = np.array(transformed.T)

        # Check if pixel is within image boundaries   
        if isWithinBounds(srcCols, srcRows, col, row):
            # Interpolate the color of the pixel from the four nearest pixels
            color = bilinearInterpolation(srcImg, srcX, srcY)
            
            # Set the color of the current pixel in the destination image
            destImg[row, col] = color
```

I wish to implement this without getAffineTransform or warpAffine. Any help would be much appreciated!

Sources:

1. [Transfer coordinates from one triangle to another triangle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844000/transfer-coordinates-from-one-triangle-to-another-triangle)
2. https://devendrapratapyadav.github.io/FaceMorphing/

Answer (score 2):

But you don't have corresponding triangles! This looks like 2 separates Delaunay triangulation. Maybe made on matching points, but still no matching triangles. You can't do two Delaunay triangulation, one in each image, and expect them to match. You need 1 delaunay triangulation, and then use the same edges on both sides (so, for at least one side, triangulation will not be exactly Delaunay).

Look for example at the top-right corner of your images.
On one side you have you have 4 outgoing edges (counting those we can't see because they are confused with te image border, but they have to be there), on the other you have 6 outgoing edges.

The number of edges connected to two matching vertices is supposed to be a constant (otherwise, how could you warp anything?).

So, clearly, I think (but you did not provide any code, for that, since you postulate that triangulation is correct, when I am pretty sure it is triangulation that is not. So I can only surmise), you got a two sets of matching **points**, then performed 2 Delaunay's triangulation on those 2 sets of points, expecting to be able to match triangles, even tho they are not at all the same triangles.

### Edit: how to transform

(in reply to your question in comment)

It's the same triangulations. You have a list of points p₁, p₂, p₃, ..., pₙ in the first images. A matching list of points q₁, q₂, q₃, ..., qₙ in the second image. You perform a triangulation in the 1st image. Whose output should be a list of triplets of indices, such as (1,3,4), (1, 2, 3), ... meaning that optimal triangulation in 1st image is the one made of triangle (p₁,p₃, p₄), (p₁, p₂, p₃), ...

And in the second image, you use triangulation (q₁,q₃,q₄), (q₁, q₂, q₃), ...

Even if it is not the optimal triangulation of q₁,q₂,...,qₙ (the one that maximize smallest angle). It should not be that far, if q₁,q₂,...,qₙ are not that different from p₁,p₂,...,pₙ (which they are not supposed to be, if you tried to match consistently both images).

So, transformation matrices are the one transforming coordinates in each matching triangles (there are one transformation for each pair of matching triangles).

To decide which point (x',y')  of second image matches point (x,y) of first image, you need

1. to identify in which triangle (i,j,k) (that is (pᵢ,pⱼ,pₖ)) (x,y) is,
2. Find barycentric coordinates of (x,y) inside this triangle: (x,y)=αpᵢ+βpⱼ+γpₖ
3. Assume that (x',y') have the same barycentric coordinates inside the matching triangle, that is (x',y')=αqᵢ+βqⱼ+γqₖ

Transformation matrix (for triangle (i,j,k)) is the one going from (x,y) to (x',y')

Comment: Ah yeah that makes sense. So if I only use the Delaunay triangulation for the second image, how may I produce the transformation matrix?

Comment: Thanks for this edit. So, the landmarks of the first image are used to perform Delaunay triangulation on the second image? Also, I'm not familiar with barycentric coordinates, would it still be possible to utilize my getAffineMat function in some way?